# semantic UI - Table - Centre Alignment

Tags: css, frontend, semantic-ui

Why is centre alignment not working on ?

I was expecting the text to be centre aligned when i specify the class `"center aligned"` to my  element but it does not.

However, if I specify the same class on all  elements then it works.

Shouldn't it suffice when a class is specified at  and all childrens inherit?

A fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/4woemsjt/4/

```
Basically this one does not work.

<div class="ui grid centered">
    <div class="fourteen wide column">
      <table class="ui celled collapsing table">
        <thead>
        <tr class="center aligned">
          <th class="three wide">S1</th>
          <th class="three wide">S2</th>
          <th class="two wide">S3</th>   
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>                  
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this one does

```
<div class="ui grid centered">
    <div class="fourteen wide column">
      <table class="ui celled collapsing table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="center aligned three wide">S1</th>
          <th class="center aligned three wide">S2</th>
          <th class="center aligned two wide">S3</th>   
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>                  
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to add the "center aligned" to all th-elements.

".ui.table thead th" has "text-align:left" set as default in the .css file.